# Trouble Putting a space between text and an iframe in XML

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I have an XML file with the following relevant section

```
<postText>
<![CDATA[text <br>
stuff<br />
<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/video'
 frameborder='0' marginheight='40px' allowfullscreen></iframe>]]>

</postText>
```

Using php simplexmlloader i am able to print this item however there is no space between the text and the top of the youtube video despite the 
 tags and the marginheightvariable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that you maybe misinterpreted the attribute `marginheight`.

The `marginheight` attribute does *not* define the space between `text <br>stuff<br />` and the `<iframe>`, but the space between the frame's content and the frame's top and bottom margin (i.e. *inside* the iframe).

One way to have a vertical space between your text and the iframe element is to wrap the `<iframe>` in a `<div>` and define a `margin-top` for the `<div>`:

```
<postText>
<![CDATA[text <br>
stuff<br /><div style="margin-top: 40px;">
<iframe width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/video'
 frameborder='0' marginheight='40px' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>]]>
</postText>
```